# Como instalar o WordPress Multisite?

Tags: wordpress, htaccess

Estou usando a opção de multi-sites do WordPress, mas não está funcionando como o esperado.

Já habilitei e criei os subdomínios, porém retorna:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Acredito que este problema esteja acontecendo pois:

Tenho 2 domínios

- dominio1.com é o domínio principal
- dominio2.com é um domínio adicional

o WordPress está instalado no domínio adicional e neste domínio criei os subdomínios.

Eu pensava que fosse o arquivo `.htaccess`, mas pelo visto não é:

http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Gera o erro 404, porquê não existe arquivos dentro do subdomínio. O que eu tenho que fazer para corrigir isso?

Comment: esse .htaccess que você colocou na pergunta é o do seu domínio ou do codex do Wordpres?

Answer (score 5):

Vou tentar colocar passo a passo aqui tudo o que você precisa fazer para habilitar o *Multisite do WordPress*. Vamos lá.

### Requisitos

- WordPress 3.0 ou maior. (recomendo a última versão).
- Suporte a wildcards na criação de subdomínios pelo host.

Se você precisar usar o WP MS com subdomínios, ou seja, acessar seus sites criados na instância do WP usando: `http://site1.example.com`, `http:///site2.example.com` e por aí vai, seu host irá precisar **ter o suporte de wildcards na criação de subdomínios**. Seu site principal ficaria em `http://example.com` e os outros sites em subdomínio desse domínio.

#### O que são os wildcards?

Quando você cria um subdomínio em host, você geralmente especifica o nome do subdomínio e a pasta root que ele deve ler. Por exemplo:

- `http://site1.example.com` - `/home/seuusuario/site1/public_html`
- `http://site2.example.com` - `/home/seuusuario/site2/public_html`

No entanto, você irá precisar transferir essa responsabilidade de responder as chamadas (requests) de domínios ao WP. Por isso, você tem que criar um domínio com wildcard, que responda a qualquer nome. Isso pode ser feito quando você cria o domínio usando:

- `*.example.com` -> `/home/seuusuario/example.com/public_html`

Dessa forma, qualquer request feito antes do example.com, será encaminhado para o WP instalado na pasta `/home/seuusuario/example.com/public_html`. Se o WP estiver configurado como MS ele responderá com o devido site criado dentro do MS.

### Crie os wildcards para subdomínios (pule se não for usar subdomínios)

Como explicado acima, você terá que acessar o painel de controle do seu host e criar um subdomínio com o nome de `*.example.com` ou, dependendo do host, `%.example.com`. Aponte o DocumentRoot para a pasta onde está a instalação do seu WP ou onde você irá instalar o WP.

Se você não achar essa opção ou o host não permitir, abra um chamado perguntando se é possível criar um subdomínio usando wildcards e se for, como você faz. Se o host **responder negativamente, então você só terá a opção de criar mais sites dentro do WP usando a opção de sub-diretórios**, infelizmente.

Se você já tiver criado domínios pelo painel e que deseja usar no WP MS, remova esses subdomínios.

### Habilitando o WP MS

Criada as configurações de subdomínios, vamos agora habilitar o Multisite no WordPress. Para isso, abra o arquivo `wp-config.php` e adicione a seguinte linha:

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
```

Salve o arquivo, e acesse seu WordPress pelo navegador. Faça o login na administração do WP e vá em `Tools > Network Setup`.

Escolha a forma de instalação entre **sub-domínios ou sub-pastas**. Lembre-se das configurações acima caso for usar subdomínios.

Finalize a instalação ajustando o `wp-config.php` e o `.htaccess` conforme as instruções dessa página temporária em Ferramentas.
[image: tela de configuração do multisite]

### Alterando o `wp-config.php`

Acrescente estas linhas depois daquela primeira de antes:

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true ); // <-- depois desta
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'seudominio.com.br');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

### Alterando o `.htaccess`

Agora só falta alterar o `.htaccess` pois ele é um pouco diferente quando usado com o WP MS. Abra seu `.htaccess` e substitua ele todo pelo seguinte conteúdo de acordo com o tipo de sua instalação:

#### Sub-domínios

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

#### Sub-pastas

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Depois que mudar os arquivos `wp-config.php` e `.htaccess`, vai ter que fazer login de novo e aparecerá o ambiente Network completo.
[image: network menu]

### Alterando o tipo de instalação de subdomínios para subpastas ou vice-versa

Se quiser alterar o tipo de instalação de um tipo para o outro depois de ter feito uma instalação, prévia, faça o seguinte. Abra o arquivo `wp-config.php` e modifique a seguinte linha:

```
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
```

Use a flag `true` para usar a instalação por sub-domínios e `false` para usar a instalação por sub-pastas.

### Mapeamento de domínios

Mapeamento é fazer com que um site do Multisite funcione com um domínio próprio, ou seja, mapear `site.example.com` para rodar como `site.com`.

Antigamente era necessário o plugin [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) mas hoje em dia isso é nativo no WordPress. É só definir a URL do site com o domínio mapeado `site.com` e o mapeamento é feito automaticamente, observando que [os DNS e o SSL já devem estar funcionando](https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-multisite-domain-mapping/) antes de mapear o domínio.

---

Fontes:

- https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/
- https://wordpress.org/support/article/multisite-network-administration/
- https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-multisite-domain-mapping/

Answer (score 0):

Na instalação do Multisite com subdomínios você não precisa criar os subdomínios. Se você criá-los o seu servidor vai direcioná-lo pro subdomínio, que está vazio e vai dar um erro 404.

Sugiro uma leitura nesse [artigo do Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network). Faça um backup do seu site, apague tudo e reinstale do zero, seguindo o passo-a-passo da página do Codex.

Answer (score -2):

Você tem acesso a Shell?
Caso sim, dá um tailf /var/log/apache/access.log para ver em qual pasta o navegador ta chegando.

Parece que o problema é o direcionamento do dominio, a pasta onde ele está sendo direcionada não é a pasta que o wp está instalado. Apenas uma sugestão.

Comment: Entrei em contato com eles, e eles disseram que a pasta é: public_html/dominio2.com/meusubdominio . Eu tenho que adicionar algum arquivo dentro do subdomínio?

Answer (score -3):

Isso mesmo amigo, precisa de algo lá dentro para que não dê Not Found.
Mas no seu caso, pelo que entendi, você precisa fazer com que este subdomínio caia na mesma pasta do dominio atual pois quem lidará com isso será o proprio WP.

Se não usar o multilanguage, teria que fazer assim:
pt.seudominio.com.br -> Pasta com Instalação do WP em Pt
en.seudominio.com.br -> Pasta com Instalação do WP em En

Porém, vai fazer assim:
pt.seudominio.com.br -> Pasta com a única instalação do WP
en.seudominio.com.br -> Pasta com a única instalação do WP

Espero que tenha sido útil, desculpe a demora.

Comment: Multilanguage e Multisite são coisas diferentes.